# SQL: How to append IDs to the rows with duplicate values

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a table with some duplicate rows. I want to modify only the duplicate rows as follows.

Before:

```
id     col1
------------
1      vvvv
2      vvvv
3      vvvv
```

After:

```
id     col1
------------
1      vvvv
2      vvvv-2
3      vvvv-3
```

Col1 is appended with a hyphen and the value of `id` column.

Comment: Um, that doesn't make cents<g>.

Comment: Are you asking for a SQL statement to identify and modify duplicate rows?

Comment: What if there are more than 2 copies? if (4, 'vvvv') was the next row what would you want to see?

Answer (score 7):

This SQL will only update duplicates, but not the one with the lowest id :

```
update tbl
  set col1 = col1 + '-' + convert(varchar, id)
  where exists(select * from tbl t where t.col1 = tbl.col1 and t.id < tbl.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check [`IN`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm) out in Oracle Syntax. The query is not tested

```
update table1 set
col1 = col1 || id
where
id not in (
select min(id) from table1
groupby col1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do that with a sproc and cursors. I don't think it's possible in any reasonable select query.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a 2 step process, although an SQL wizard could probably modify this to give you a solution in one step.

First you need to get all the duplicate values. Here is an SQL query that will do that:

```
SELECT     COUNT(*) AS NumberOfDuplicates, col1
FROM         Table1
GROUP BY col1
HAVING      (COUNT(*) > 1)
```

This will give you a resultset listing the number of duplicates and the duplicate value.

In step 2 you would loop through this resultset, fetch the col1 value, return all the records containing that value and (possibly using a loop counter variable) alter the value as per your example.

Note: you don't really need to return the number of duplicates to achieve your goal, but it will help you to test the query and be satisfied that it works.